# Creating a Folder with a User-Generated String Variable in v2.0 Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a folder named after a concatenated variable generated by the user. My unit only has access to powershell v2.0, so I'm unable to utilize the following lines of code to create a folder based on the name:

```
$mission = ("Boss " + $location + " Mission")
New-Item -Name $mission -ItemType Directory -Path "Q:\NEW ET PUB\3 EXEC TRAVEL TEAM(msn trng, sched, reports, SOP, etc..)\Mission Planning\1 - Upcoming Missions\"
```

or this

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "Q:\NEW ET PUB\3 EXEC TRAVEL TEAM(msn trng, sched, reports, SOP, etc..)\Mission Planning\1 - Upcoming Missions\$mission"
```

I saw on another article that I should try something similar to the below code, but I'm getting the same error as the code above.

```
$path = "Q:\NEW ET PUB\3 EXEC TRAVEL TEAM(msn trng, sched, reports, SOP, etc..)\Mission Planning\1 - Upcoming Missions\"
if(!(test-path $path)){new-item -ItemType Directory -Path $Path -Name $mission -force}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the error? What's the content of `$location`?

Comment: New-Item : Item with specified name Q:\NEW ET PUB\3 EXEC TRAVEL TEAM(msn trng, sched, reports, SOP, etc..)\Mission Planning\1 - Upcoming Missions\ already exists. And $location contains a String entered via user input.

Comment: Well, then I assume, the folder indeed already exists, doesn't it? If you want to supress errors if the folder already exists use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem with your 2nd variant:

```
> $location = 'test'
> $mission = ("Boss " + $location + " Mission")
> New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "Q:\NEW ET PUB\3 EXEC TRAVEL TEAM(msn rng, sched, reports, SOP, etc..)\Mission Planning\1 - Upcoming Missions\$mission"

> tree Q:
Q:\
└───NEW ET PUB
    └───3 EXEC TRAVEL TEAM(msn trng, sched, reports, SOP, etc..)
        └───Mission Planning
            └───1 - Upcoming Missions
                └───Boss test Mission
```